# Flutter : how to set itemCount length in IndexedListView builder

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scroll, builder

i am trying to scrolling to an specific index by its index number in at ListView. i used to IndexedListView builder from https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view/example. but i got error in "itemCount: myData.length", so have been unable to use a fix arrange in ListView.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

static IndexedScrollController controller =
  IndexedScrollController(initialIndex: 0);

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: IndexedListView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                child: Center(child: Text('ITEM $index')),),);},),),
      Container(height: 3.0, color: Colors.black),
      Container(
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(onTap: () {controller.jumpToIndex(5);},
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(child: Text("Button to go to An specific index", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),),),)],),),],),);}
   }
```

Comment: Could you please explain it in detail or sshare the code?

Comment: @RajuGupta please recheck my question. i added full code. thank you.

Comment: @RajuGupta hello friend

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding `itemCount = your_list_length.length` inside your `ListView.builder`

```
       child: ListView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          itemCount = your_list_length.length
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                child: Center(child:
```

ps: answer for using `ListView`, there is no need to specify `itemCount` if you were using `IndexedListView`

Comment: Error: No named parameter with the name 'itemCount'.
              itemCount: myData.length,

Comment: @EmmaScarlett try to use `ListView` instead of `IndexedListView`

Comment: i used to IndexedListView according to this one https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view/example

Comment: @EmmaScarlett From the  [link](https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view/example) you have posted, `If you want to move the list programmatically you must create a scroll controller of type IndexedScrollController and pass it in the list constructor. However, if all you need is an infinite list without jumps, then there is no need to even create a controller.` There is no need to set itemCount, unless you are using ListView

Comment: can be more details please, because i am new here

Comment: @EmmaScarlett I advise you to read README section inside the link you have posted. The answer is there, and there is no need to initialize itemCount

Comment: there are a lot of "empty" item to be displayed instead, As default. how to stop this. suppose i set 10 data, but it display so many empty data after complete show 10 data.

Comment: @EmmaScarlett if you want to set a fixed `10 data`, i suggest you to use ListView where you can fixed the length of the list you want. Coming back to your question `there are a lot of "empty" item to be displayed instead`. As mentioned inside the link you provide, `Limitation: The list is always infinite both to positive and negative indexes. In other words, it can be scrolled indefinitely both to the top and to the bottom.`. Again I hope you can read the README section before questioning your doubt. It helps, trust me:D

Comment: how it possible to show same data again from start when will  be no more data.

Comment: Its infinite both to positive and negative indexes

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `ListView.builder` working code, try it out

```
 Widget _ExampleListView(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        itemCount: yourLength.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTap: () {
              //what you want to do when tapping on each list
              // tap each column to see the index
              print(index);
            },
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('text1'),
                          Text('text2'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
    );
  }
```